# ngb-carousel changing starting slide

Tags: angular, slide, lifecycle, ng-bootstrap

I am using Angular 5 and `ngb-carousel`. The carousel has 3 slides on the template, each one with a different id. I would like to set the starting slide based on data that is passed to the component hosting the slide.

The problem I am running into is that if I used `@ViewChild` to get a reference to the carousel it is undefined on the `ngOnOnit` hook, so I cannot do anything there. It is "not" undefined in the `ngAfterViewInit` hook, so I can call the `select()` function to change the slide, but then I run into the "Expression has changed after it was checked." error. In summary, `@ViewChild` does not return carousel at the time of `ngOnInit`, and if I change the slide viewed during `ngAfterViewInit` I get the change error.

Is there a better approach to set the starting slide for ngb-carousel based on data passed to the component?

Comment: can you do <ngb-carousel #carousel *ngIf="images" [activeId]="yourvariable">?

Comment: Actually that works as well, and the variable can be set in ngOnInit (just tested it) which is preferable. One thing that also causing problems is that the id assign to the slide apparently were not unique on the document and that makes any changes to activeId not take change. But it works as you suggested. Thank you.

Comment: If you has the slides in a *ngFor you can give id dinamicaly using, e.g. id="{{'slide'+i}}

Answer (score 0):

I think I got a workaround. Given that @ViewChild will not get a reference of ngb-carousel in time for ngOnInit, and that I have to call select() in the ngAfterViewInit hook, then wrapping the select call as shown below in a SetTimeout call will ensure that the current Javascript VM cycle will finish without affecting the view, then the change is made which is perfectly legal. More about this in this link:

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-what-is-unidirectional-data-flow-development-mode/

Here the code that works:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.carousel.select('3');
    });
}
```